# Degree of an even/odd part of a formal power series over a polynomial ring

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, power-series

Let $K$ be a field with $\operatorname{char}K\ne 2$ (say, $K=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) and consider a formal power series $f=f(x)\in K[[x]]$ such that $[K[x,f]:K[x]\,]=d$. Suppose $f_e,f_o\in K[[x]]$ are such that $f(x)=f_e(x^2)+xf_o(x^2)$. What can be said in general about the values of (or upper bounds on) $d_e=[K[x,f_e(x)]:K[x]\,]$ and $d_o=[K[x,f_o(x)]:K[x]\,]$ ? Any references would be helpful.

For example, the Catalan generating function $C=C(x)\in\mathbb{R}[[x]]$ satisfies $1-C+xC^2=0$, so $d=2$. Letting $C(x)=C_e(x^2)+xC_o(x^2)$, we get $C_e,C_o\in\mathbb{R}[[x]]$ such that $C_e(x)=\sqrt{C(4x)}$ and $xC_o(x)=(xC(x))\circ(xC(4x))$, so $d_e=d_o=4$.

It would seem that the answer here may have something to do with $d$ and $2$, perhaps $2d$ or $d^2$, but I don't know if either of those is correct.

Comment: They are at most $d^2$, since both odd and even part are expressed via $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$